# Oracle ADF Login Application - MySql - jDeveloper - Integrated WebLogic

Tags: mysql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am creating Oracle ADF web application. In that I need to authenticate user using login process. I am using

- MySql DataBase
- jDeveloper
- Integrated WebLogic Server

By using the following tutorial I have created a login application.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_57/jdtut_11r2_57.html

In the above tutorial password is hard-coded in the managed bean. But my requirement is I need to check the user entered value with the data base table value. I am using MySql as database.

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You don't specify version or if you are using ADF BC or JPA or another mechanism for DB access. answers those Q's and I'll try to help. If all you are asking is "how do I read/write to a table from a Java class? then it use standard JDBC. If using ADF BC/Data controls, things can be done declaratively w/o much code.

Comment: Refer to: http://biemond.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-database-tables-as-authentication.html